# Preventing Tomcat from appending charset to binary content types

Tags: tomcat, servlets, restlet

We have a Restlet based service that returns the following response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1, Restlet-Framework/2.0.7
X-Powered-By: Servlet 2.4; JBoss-4.2.3.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_3_GA date=200807181417)/JBossWeb-2.0
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=Time_for_a_breather.pdf
Date: Fri, 13 May 2011 23:41:24 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: application/pdf;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 218495
```

but unfortunately within some browsers (Chrome in particular) we are having problems viewing the pdf.

From experimenation and research it appears the problem is related to jBoss/Tomcat appending charset=UTF-8 to the Content Type which causes the browser to sense that its receiving text data not binary data.

Does anybody know of a way from preventing jBoss/Tomcat appending the charset to the content type for binary data?

Answer (score 1):

The servletcontainer does that only when you have a

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

somewhere in your code. See also the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setCharacterEncoding%28java.lang.String%29). Setting the character encoding makes no sense for binary data, so just don't do that on requests for binary data.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it turned out to be Spring's `CharacterEncodingFilter`. If you set `forceEncoding` to `true`, it will add the character encoding to the content type, even if it makes no sense as for binary data.

In order to fix it, set the `forceEncoding` to `false` or leave it in the default setting. And verify the effect it has, e.g. on JSON responses.

Answer (score 0):

At this stage I have been unable to stop Tomcat from appending charset=UTF-8 to the Content-Type header which is causing Chrome PDFViewer (internal PDF viewer) to fail viewing the PDF document.

While experimenting I have discovered that if I don't return the Content-Length and set Transfer-Encoding=chunked then the PDF is viewable by Chrome's PDFViewer. This is a workaround for the moment but probably a fragile solution.

Comment: Actually, it's the default response encoding when you don't set the `Content-Length` header. You don't explicitly need to set the `Transfer-Encoding` header yourself.