# Issue with restcontroller and application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8 media type

Tags: java, spring, rest, controller, media-type

Task is trivial
client sends request using POST with application/x-www-form-urlencoded media type. Server receives and response with status OK. But looks like there is difference between media type **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** and **application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8**

Server part:

```
@Slf4j
@Controller
@RequestMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public class CallbackController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/callback/", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> callback(HttpServletRequest servletRequest, @RequestBody RequestEntity<?> body) throws IOException {
        log.info("Hello: {}", servletRequest);
        log.info("Hello: {}", body);
        String s = extractPostRequestBody(servletRequest);
        log.info("Hello: {}", s);
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Client part:

```
public void sendcallback() throws IOException {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String url = "http://localhost:8082/callback/";
        MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE);
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_CHARSET, "UTF-8");
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE);
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, "uuuuuuuuuuser");
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "none");
MultiValueMap<String, String> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
        List<String> val1 = new ArrayList<>();
        val1.add("valllll");
        body.put("val", val1);
        HttpEntity<?> entity= new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);
        ResponseEntity<?> result = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, Object.class);
        log.info("response: {}", result);
    }
```

the result output at client side, request:

```
"POST /callback/ HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded[\r][\n]"
"Accept-Charset: UTF-8[\r][\n]"
"Accept: application/x-www-form-urlencoded[\r][\n]"
"User-Agent: uuuuuuuuuuser[\r][\n]"
"Authorization: none[\r][\n]"
"Content-Length: 11[\r][\n]"
"Host: localhost:8082[\r][\n]"
"Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
"Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
"[\r][\n]"
"val=valllll"
```

response:

```
"HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed[\r][\n]"
"Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1[\r][\n]"
"Allow: GET, HEAD[\r][\n]"
"Content-Language: ru-RU[\r][\n]"
"Content-Length: 0[\r][\n]"
"Date: Tue, 11 Aug 2015 06:28:41 GMT[\r][\n]
"[\r][\n]"
```

and server in debug mode tell me interesting thing:

[image]

Comment: Check this if it helps you, character encoding filter      
http://stackoverflow.com/a/28880779/5138955

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like I have to add FormHttpMessageConverter manually

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CallbackApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CallbackApplication.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        FormHttpMessageConverter converter = new FormHttpMessageConverter();
        MediaType mediaType = new MediaType("application","x-www-form-urlencoded", Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(mediaType));
        converters.add(converter);
        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }
}
```

And don't forget to use correct @RequestBody type

`public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<?> callback(HttpServletRequest servletRequest, @RequestBody MultiValueMap body)`{

Since there are:

- **org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap**
- org.apache.commons.collections.map.MultiValueMap